# HTTP 400 - Java spring-boot webapp with tomcat 10 is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat10

I wanted to check if my application is running with Apache Tomcat 10.0.12.
It works with Apache Tomcat 9.0.54 just fine.

In the manager the application is marked as running. The logfiles also say the application was deployed. There are no errors.

```
29-Oct-2021 16:53:38.111 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploye Web-Applikations-Verzeichnis [...\Tomcat10\webapps\ROOT]
29-Oct-2021 16:53:41.639 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
29-Oct-2021 16:53:41.653 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [...\Tomcat10\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [3.541] ms
```

When opening my application in the browser I'm getting this:

```
HTTP Status 404 – nicht gefunden
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/] is not available

Beschreibung The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/10.0.12
```

How can I check what the problem is? I've tried to deploy my application with another context than ROOT but that changed nothing.
Also opening index.html didn't change anything.